# Joining 3 tables with similar structure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm executing sql queries in oracle 10g.

I want to join 3 tables into a single new table containing all the records from the 3 individual tables. The balance should be Summed up wherever the reg_id is duplicated between the 3 tables, such that there is just one entry per reg_id with the summed balance in my new table.

Sample data ( similar tables, with different values ) . tables : temp1, temp2, temp3

```
reg_id    |            balance
--------------------------------
92603013               183.77
92611902               419.46
92766121               77.04
93527720               24.84
93581368               120.09
93684684                89.88
93527720               113.66
```

Appreciate if someone can help me with the syntax.

Comment: Can there be same reg_id values in a single table ? Can there be some reg_ids that are present in one table but not in the other two ?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following...

```
INSERT INTO target_table (reg_id, balance)
SELECT reg_id, sum(balance) as balance
FROM (select reg_id, balance from temp1
      UNION ALL
      select reg_id, balance from temp2
      UNION ALL
      select reg_id, balance from temp3)
GROUP BY reg_id;
```

I haven't tried it so don't know if the syntax is correct and whether it'll will horribly mangle your data.  :)

EDIT: Changed UNION to UNION ALL.  Thanks, APC!

EDIT 2: Specified the columns explicitly per Tony's recommendation.

Comment: This is basically the right idea except you should use UNION ALL not UNION.  If the same REG_ID just happens to appear in two tables with the same value for BALANCE it should be counted twice,  UNION filters out duplicates.

Comment: +1 But the "select *" syntax will only work if all 3 tables have identical columns; "select reg_id, balance" would be safer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.reg_id, t2.reg_id, t3.reg_id) AS the_reg_id,
       coalesce(t1.balance, 0.0) + 
       coalesce(t2.balance, 0.0) +
       coalesce(t3.balance, 0.0) AS the_balance
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.reg_id = t2.reg_id)
        FULL OUTER JOIN t3 ON (t1.reg_id = t3.reg_id)
```